# My 4-year-old wants fairy to grant her wishes - how to keep the magic alive without always having to buy presents?

Tags: pre-schooler, age-appropriate, presents

My 4-year-old daughter asked the fairy for a specific toy. I want to keep the magic alive, but don’t want to buy gifts everytime she posts her wishes to her fairy....
I’m looking for an age-appropriate response, that will keep her believing, without bankrupting mum.

Comment: This is a different way to frame things that admittedly doesn't mesh with the "magic". When our kids (Even preshchool aged) wanted something, we found something that they could do to earn the money for it. When the job was done, they were paid. If they still wanted it, we took them to the store to buy it. We paid market rates, same as if we hired someone else to do the job. No magic, but they learned basic economics early.

Answer (score 6):

This made me smile. I have a daughter 15 now, but at similar age she also used to post wishes to the fairy. We actually had a fairy in one of the flower pots at home and although it is now a bit battered and worse for wear it is still there. Yes, you want to keep the magic alive but financially it can be difficult. We used to say the fairy had taken note of the wish and would try and grant it on her special day (as in her birthday) but if she over wished the fairy would run out of magic, so she should only makes wishes that really mattered to her.

Answer (score 5):

Make a chart with a set of boxes (less than 10, more than 2), each big enough to fit a sticky note (or use a whiteboard or blackboard or ... whatever). Keep the wishes in each box and mark the fairy's "wish-granting date" on the chart. Let your child know that when the date rolls around, the fairy will take all the notes and grant **one** wish.

This allows your child to start forming ideas about time, patience, anticipation, and choice. If your child really really really wants one item, all of the boxes could be filled in the same to drive the point home to the fairy.

At the fairy's discretion, more wishes could be granted in a period if your child has shown exceptional behaviour (and if granting more wishes doesn't cause you to bankrupt yourself).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just use something like Santa and say that the fairy only brings toys (or large gifts or whatever) on special occasions like a birthday or other designated day.  This way you set up expectations that wishes are not always immediately fulfilled (teaches patience) and keeps whims from breaking the bank.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use his wishes to teach him good moral value and to make sure your child is practically implementing them by assuring your child that fairy can fulfill your one wish only for his good deed after some time interval and for this he has to write all his deed good or bad on his dairy along with his wishes,and daily he has to mark one from all of his wishes which is his deepest desire then you should check his dairy and if there is some that you want him to continue than you provide him.If he do some thing unacceptable than fairy will not reward him until he apologize and you may punish him in silent way so that he have strong faith on virtue and its reward.By this you can also develop a decision power in your child.